# BeautifulSoup Scraping: loading div instead of the content

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Noob here. 
I'm trying to scrape search results from this website: http://www.mastersportal.eu/search/?q=di-4|lv-master&order=relevance

I'm using python's BeautifulSoup

```
import csv
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

for numb in ('0', '69'):
        url = ('http://www.mastersportal.eu/search/?q=ci-30,11,10,3,4,8,9,14,15,16,17,34,1,19|di-4|lv-master|rv-1&start=' + numb + '0&order=tuition_eea&direction=asc')
        response = requests.get(url)
        html = response.content

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        table = soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'StudySearchResults'})

        lista = []
        for i in table.findAll('h3'):
            lista.append(h3.string)
print(table.prettify())
```

I want to get clean data with the basic information about the Master (for now just the name).
The URL I'm using here is for a filtered research on the website and the loop to go on with pages should be fine.

However, the results are:

```
<div id="StudySearchResults">
  <div style="display:none" id="TrackingSearchValue" class="TrackingSearchValue" data-search=""></div>
  <div style="display:none" id="SearchViewEvent" class="TrackingEvent TrackingNoLocation" data-type="srch" data-action="view" data-id=""></div>
  <div id="StudySearchResultsStudies" class="TrackingLinkedList" data-start="" data-list-type="study" data-type="rslts">
    <!-- Wait pane, just here to make sure there is no white page -->
    <div id="WaitPane" class="WaitPane">
      <img src="http://www.mastersportal.eu/Modules/Results/Resources/Throbber.gif" />
      <span>Loading search results...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why isn't the content displaying but only the loading div? Reading around I feel it has something to do with the way the website handles data with JavaScript, does something like an AJAX request exist for Python? (or any other way to tell the scraper to wait for the page to load?)

Comment: Try `h3.get_text()` instead of `h3.string`. [Docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Comment: The page is making ajax requests to get the data json in format, you need to query the api endpoints directly (check the network tab in Chrome devtools)

Comment: what are you trying to get from the page, what is "master"?

Comment: @WalidSaad thanks, but I have no idea on how to start from with that, you have any suggestion on something I could read about how to use Chrome devtools to scrape?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have basically answered your own question. Beautiful Soup is a pure web scraper which will only download whatever the server returns for a specific URL.

If you want to render the page as it is shown in a browser, you will need to use something like [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) which will start up an actual browser and remote control it.

While using Webdriver is very powerful, it has a much steeper learning curve than pure web scraping as well though.

If you want to get into using Webdriver with Python, the [official documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. You're right, at my level this may be a bit tough to dive into but strongly needed!

Comment: Go for it by all means. I didn't mean to deter you, but meant to make sure that you know what you're in for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the text, you should do this

```
lista.append(h3.get_text())
```

Regarding your second question, jsfan's answer is right. You should try Selenium and use its [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) feature to wait for your search results, that appear in `divs` with the class names `Result master premium`

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "div[@class*='Result master premium']))
)
```

Comment: Right, I'll firstly need to understand the use of Selenium and then I'll use this method. Thanks!