# Unable to scrape <li> tag inside the <ol> tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape the search results i.e. li tag inside the ol tag using beautiful soup on New York Times website using the following python query-

```
theurl =["http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/Microsoft/"] 
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup=BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
for profile in soup.findAll("ol",attrs={"class":"searchResultsList flush"}):
   print(profile)
```

But it simply returns the following results,

```
<ol class="searchResultsList flush">
</ol>
```

and doesn't return the li list tags inside the ol tag. I have tried replacing "html.parser" with "lxml" that didn't help. I am thinking it may be a security parameter that doesn't let me scrape the search results  can anyone please confirm this or has a solution to this? Thanks

Comment: it shows the correct output. There is no li tags present inside `searchResultsList` class.

Comment: Duplicate of [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535039/beautifulsoup-scraping-loading-div-instead-of-the-content)
Please take a look at the answers there. You're having the same problem

Comment: @AvinashRaj their in where lies the problem its not parsing li tags in the soup variable. If you'll visit the link in the question and inspect any of the search results you will find those tags.
Obsidian it suggests the use of selenium webdriver, I'll get back to you once I figure out how to work it.

Comment: @Obsidian the post talks about website restrictions that allows only 10 searches per second and to overcome this introducing a delay in the query. This is actually the API limit of NYT that allows 10 searches per second and 10,000 searches per day. I was actually using beautiful soup to avoid using the API because of its limit as introducing a one second delay for 10 results would mean 30 seconds for 300, leaving the query inefficient. Anyway wish their was a better way to do this but thanks for your help.

Comment: @Uasthana if that is the bottleneck on the backend, I don't think you can overcome it unless you decide to spawn multiple requests. The page itself indirectly is a user of the API and will be subject to the same limitation, making any crawler not serve your purpose. Good luck!